# Reading routing parameter in HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

We can set the routing parameter through HTML:

```
<a [routerLink] = "['/api/foo/', id]"/>
```

I know that we can read routing parameter through handling event in the *typescript*:

```
import {OnInit, OnDestroy, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let Id = params['id'];
        console.log(Id);
      });
  }
}
```

However, is there any way to read route parameter in the HTML, not in the TypeScript component?

I would like to use in the following manner:

```
<a href="api/foo/[routerLink]"/>
```

Comment: What's stopping you to read params in your component?

Comment: Show me where did you use it in HTML?

Comment: You can't use it like that, it just doesn't work

Comment: @RomanC and that's my question. ISs there any way to use `router` in HTML.

Comment: @downvoter what is a reason to downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the param in html it is better to assign the param to a variable and use it in html

```
private param:number;

private ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.param = params['id'];
        console.log(this.param);
      });
  }
```

in your html

```
<div>{{param}}</div>
```

Comment: Am not sure OP want this or not.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get id as number. You can use this.

```
id:number;

 ngOnInit() {

        this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
          (params: any) => {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
               id= +params['id'];
              //do whatever you want
            }
          }
        );

      }
```

and this destroyed the subscription

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

and you can access the `id` field on html side.